# Power calculation for Spearman correlation

Tags: r, statistical-power, spearman-rho

Suppose, I am generating data from bivariate normal distribution with means 0 and variances 1 and correlation coefficient 0,0.5 and 1. I need to calculate power for different correlations. 
I am doing this simulation in R but when I change my correlation coefficient to 0.5, my power is always one. I think I am missing something here. For correlation coefficient 0, i get my power to be around 0.05 which makes sense but for others it is not.

Comment: try r = 0.1 see if it give you the power between 0.05 and 1. maybe r = 0.5 results in power is nearly 1.

Comment: Actually I just ran 500 simulations for 0.1 and 0.2. With 0.1 the power is 0.858 and with 0.2 it is 1. There must be something wrong here.

Comment: sample size? Maybe the sample size is so large such that tiny difference from 0 will be detected.

Comment: Maybe, I am using sample size of 1000.

Comment: When sample size > 10000, everything is significant, cited from a professor.So decrease the sample size to 100, to prove that your program is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard error of a Spearman sample correlation under the null of no correlation will be about $1/\sqrt{n}\approx 0.0316$ and the null distribution of the correlation is approximately normal. A correlation near $0.5$ will be about $15.8$ such standard errors from $0$; i.e. with such a large sample size giving a large standardized effect size, you expect to have power essentially at $1$.